# How to avoid creating a subfolder when cloning a repository

Tags: git

The project on gilab is contained in the **spend** folder.
I'm creating an empty folder at my local and run `git init`.
Then I execute the command `git clone <repo adress> .` With a dot at the end and get

```
fatal: destination path '.' already exists and is not an empty directory.
```

If I remove the dot at the end, the repository is uploaded to the subfolder.

```
spend
    .git
    spend
        repo_file and folder
```

How can I do this without creating an extra folder?

Comment: If you are creating a repo by doing `git clone`, then you don't have to do `git init` in the first place.

Comment: @mnestorov great, that's it. Thank you for your help.

Comment: It might also help if you remember that `git clone` means run these six commands: *mkdir; git init; git remote add; git config; git fetch; git checkout*. The first one creates the directory in which the `git init` runs and all the rest run in that directory. Since one of the six *is* `git init`, you don't need your own `git init`.

Comment: @torek thanks for the helpful information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this project already exists somewhere and you are getting it by `git clone`, a previous step of `git init` is not needed.

Thus, go to your directory, where you want the project folder to be, then do a simple `git clone`.